# Better way to handle value conversion for mixed variable types in an array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with a [generally not widely used] PHP framework in which the class I'm currently working with has an array of fields that correlate to columns in SQL.

Well, for setting values for class objects there's a class method setFieldValue and conventionally something like this would be done:

```
protected $fields = array('id', 'name', 'body');

function setFieldValue($field, $value) {
    switch($field) {
        case 'id':
            return parent::setFieldValue($field, intval($value));
        case 'name':
            return parent::setFieldValue($field, strval($value));
        case 'body':
            return parent::setFieldValue($field, strval($value));
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something a bit more dynamic (and cleaner, as I'll have many fields), maybe like:

```
protected $fields = array('id' => 'intval', 'name' => 'strval', 'body' => 'strval');

function setFieldValue($field, $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($field, $this->fields)) {
        return parent::setFieldValue($field, $fields[$field]($value));
    }
}
```

Would anyone consider this alternative I'm suggesting bad practice and furthermore would anyone suggest other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it looks good because the name of the fields aren't promoted to the outside of that class in both cases - the `switch` or the `array_key_exists`. So this *should* not make any difference, because you solve it internally (privately) which is invisible.

Run your unit-tests before and after the changes to see if everything went smoothly.

Comment: I forget the term, but calling a function from a string value...I've been under the impression that's something to avoid with the exception of instancing dynamic class objects, do you have any opinion on that?

Comment: What you refer to is like: `setID($id), setName($name), setBody($body) ` etc. But that's not the case anyway in your two examples. From a developers standpoint most often explicit interfaces (everything has a defined name, in your case every field) is better than a wishy-washy name in a string. However, there are exceptions to this rule. Consider what's best for you. For the two examples you gave, there is no difference as the public interface does not change.

Comment: Explicit interfaces were given on top of this code, I see where this is going and very much appreciate your help.  What you've said has helped give me a better understanding and I very much appreciate it, this is exactly what I was looking for when I made this post. (I just wish I had gotten more responses from other developers)

Comment: @ShawnKhameneh: The topic is fairly straight forward. Explicit interfaces allow you to more precisely deal with things. You could generate the model classes with the named getters/setters based on a definition per each type (e.g. the names of fields, their type and whether those are read-only). The first example only has `setFieldValue` which is not explicit, but takes the field name as string and falls-through when a specific key is not matched. Putting the field-names into an array is easier to configure, because you don't need to write the switch statement so I would prefer it over the 1st.